# Exporting A DLL - Remove the header file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, header-files

I've done some research on this and haven't found anything so I'm posting here.

I'm trying to export a framework I created into a DLL, and I've done this. My problem is I would like to remove the .h attachment so people can't read it when I'm ready to publish.

I'm sure this is possible. I've gone into closed source programs and games and they have DLLs, and no headers. It's really as simple as that, I'm just not sure how.

**Tech Info:**

- Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio 2013 RC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compile a new program against a DLL, it needs the header files. However, once this new program is compiled, it no longer needs the headers - the links have already been setup by the compiler. You should be able to distribute just the executable, as well as the binary DLL files it links against.

Have you tried simply removing the header files? I'm assuming Visual Studio creates them because, like I said, to write new code against an existing library, you need to know the function signatures, but you should be able to just remove them and still run the application.

It also might be worth noting that, generally speaking, distributing headers for a closed-source application isn't really a problem. All the header files contain is, "I have a function called f which takes parameters A, B and C," which isn't super sensitive information. Generally, with a closed source application, the information you want to keep a secret is *how the functions are implemented*, not what their signatures are.

Comment: No, I never thought it would be that easy. Let me try, one second.

Comment: It really is that easy. I'm so sorry, I never even thought it would be so easy. Thanks for the fast and simple response.